# How to reference to other periods or columns when using aggregate()

Tags: r, aggregate

When using aggregate, how can I make reference to a previous period within the function? 
For example if aggregating by days how can make reference to the previous day from the next day in order to calculate the function.

For example if I had a one year hourly time series and I like to calculate the maximum of one day minus the minimum of the previous day I could use two different aggregates, shifting one of them and substracting from the other, but how could I do it all from within just one aggregate?

How can I know the number of the piece (here the day) where am I in order to use it inside the function?

cheers

Comment: edit your question to show the code correctly (see the 101010 icon), and add which type your data is. Right now it's quite impossible to get what you're heading at. Your aggregate construct is completely faulty (no index provided and 2 functions provided)

Comment: I've modified it. I really don't know how to write it, that's why I ask it in abstract.

Comment: @user425895 Just add some sample code, but put it in as code. The "tail" function in your sample code was really odd, I had no clue whatsoever what you were trying to do. If you need aggregate to access a previous result, you might want to rethink your approach again.

Comment: @user,I'm sorry, but really doesn't make sense to me...Maybe you could add a samply data and provide a short example. what is a `piece`?

Comment: If I aggregate by whole days a piece would be one day, if aggregating by 2 hours then 2 hours....

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have it appropriately sorted, you can use the `shift()` function I provided in response to [a (much more specific) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450255/calculate-scores-across-columns/5451212#5451212).

Comment: If anyone has suggestions on how to avoid using my kludged-together shift() function, please let me know.  It does seem like someone's written such a function before.