# Calculate scores across columns

Tags: r

First the sample data:

```
bbbv[1:25] <-1
bbbv[26:50] <-2
bbbw <- 1:25
bbbx <- sample(1:5, 50, replace=TRUE)
bbby <- sample(1:5, 50, replace=TRUE)

bbb <- data.frame(pnum=bbbv, trialnum=bbbw, guess=bbbx, target=bbby)
```

If the target is the same number as the guess then we score 1, else 0.

```
bbb$hit <- ifelse(bbb$guess==bbb$target, 1, 0)
```

[image]

This is the problem. I want to calculate four more columns:

```
bbb$hitpone trialnum(n) guess == trial(n+1) target
bbb$hitptwo trialnum(n) guess == trial(n+2) target
bbb$hitmone trialnum(n) guess == trial(n-1) target
bbb$hitmtwo trialnum(n) guess == trial(n-2) target
```

To be clear. For hitmone we look at the trial guess and compare it to the target for the trial before (-1 from the current trial). For hitmtwo we look at the trial guess and compare it to the target 2 back (-2 from the current trial). hitpone and hitptwo are the same but in a positive direction (+1 and +2 from current trial).

And just to be clear, as before we're interested in determining If the target is the same number as the guess then we score 1, else 0 (according to our new calculations).

Now there is some minor difficulty with this task. Each pnum has 25 trials. For hitpone we cannot calculate a +1 for trial 25. For hitptwo we cannot calculate a +2 for trials 25 nor trial 24. The same follows for the hitmone: we cannot calculate -1 for trial 1, nor -2 for trials 1 and 2.

This is how I want the table to look. I have mocked it up by hand, showing the first 1-3 trials and last 23-25 trials.
[image: Wanted output]

```
dput(bbb)
structure(list(pnum = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), trialnum = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L), guess = c(5L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), 
target = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L), hit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), .Names = c("pnum", "trialnum", "guess", 
"target", "hit"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please dput(bbb) and show us the output so we can easily reproduce.  Also, it's unclear to me what your pseudocode for what you want done means.  Maybe type out in words how you want a specific entry of e.g. hitpone calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the basics.  You can extend this out to handle negative increments and use `by()` to wrap a call to `hitp()` to avoid subsetting.

```
hitp <- function(dtf,inc) {
    target.shift <- shift(dtf$target,inc,wrap=FALSE,pad=TRUE)
    return(dtf$guess==target.shift)
}
bbb1 <- subset(bbb,pnum==1)
bbb1$hitpone <- hitp(bbb1,1)
bbb1$hitptwo <- hitp(bbb1,2)
bbb1$hitmone <- hitp(bbb1,-1)
```

Call to by would look something like this:

```
unlist(by(bbb,bbb$pnum,hitp,inc=1))
```

Where `shift` is a program I wrote for another purpose:

```
shift <- function(vec,n=1,wrap=TRUE,pad=FALSE) {
    if(length(vec)<abs(n)) { 
        #stop("Length of vector must be greater than the magnitude of n \n") 
    }
    if(n==0) { 
        return(vec) 
    } else if(length(vec)==n) { 
        # return empty
        length(vec) <- 0
        return(vec)
    } else if(n>0) {
        returnvec <- vec[seq(n+1,length(vec) )]
        if(wrap) {
            returnvec <- c(returnvec,vec[seq(n)])
        } else if(pad) {
            returnvec <- c(returnvec,rep(NA,n))
        }
    } else if(n<0) {
        returnvec <- vec[seq(1,length(vec)-abs(n))]
        if(wrap) {
            returnvec <- c( vec[seq(length(vec)-abs(n)+1,length(vec))], returnvec )
        } else if(pad) {
            returnvec <- c( rep(NA,abs(n)), returnvec )
        }

    }
    return(returnvec)
}
```

This all relies pretty heavily on proper sorting, so make sure it's sorted before you run.

Comment: Thanks @gsk3. It's a bit advanced for my skills, but I've given it a go. Do I have to run `bbb1 <- subset(bbb,pnum==1)` for all pnums? Or does the unlist calculate for all of them? I'm not sure.

Comment: @Rsoul: The subsetting is simply so you can peek under the hood a bit.  `by(bbb,bbb$pnum,hitp,inc=1)` will run it on each pnum.  The unlist just puts it back into a form where it can be inserted back into bbb.  So `bbb$hitpone <- unlist(by(bbb,bbb$pnum,hitp,inc=1))` should do what you want.  Don't get all bogged down in the details of `shift`.  Fundamentally all it does is shift a vector by an increment.  Just consider it a black box that you load into R by copy/pasting the code.  Put your effort into understanding `hitp()`.

Comment: Ah. That helps. So any hints how I get the negative increments? :)

Comment: Why, you rewrite the shift() function of course :-).  See above.

Comment: @RSoul: No problem.  Hitp is a simple enough function here that it's worth spending the time to see how it works, because vectorization in R is a powerful tool.  The other way to do this would have been with a loop, but this seems simpler and faster (given that I'd already written shift() ).  There also may be a built-in shift-like function that I don't know about.